# Установка Bootstrap 5 на Laravel 9 с помощью npm

Tags: laravel, bootstrap, npm, bootstrap5, laravel-9

Возможно данный вопрос задавался уже не раз, но хочется получить актуальный ответ на этот вопрос.
Чаще всего на этот вопрос предлагают установить пакет `laravel ui`, но он уже давно объявлен **legacy** и такой вариант не подходит...

Подскажите какие команды нужно выполнить, какие нюансы нужно учесть при установке, какие параметры нужно указать в `webpack.mix.js` и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, собственно, Вас `webpack` тут особо волновать не должен.

```
npm i bootstrap
```

В `webpack.mix.js` (если там сильно ничего не поменялось, а вроде бы не должно):

```
mix.react('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

В `resources/js/app.js`:

```
import 'bootstrap';
```

В `resources/sass/app.scss`:

```
/*
    Тут можно переопределить переменные scss от Bootstrap
    Например:
    grid-columns: 20;
*/
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

Скомпилированные файлы уже вставляете в шаблонах как обычно, по документации.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вот в документации бутстрапа приводятся примеры такие примеры подключения `@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";` но нигде не объясняется что означает путь который начинается с ~

Comment: @АнатолийШевелев Это алиас. Иногда ещё бывает, что пишут `@`, `@@`, `~~`. По сути означает или прямой путь до корня, или путь до конкретной папки. Они где-то явно указываются в webpack, но не возьмусь сказать, где именно. В Laravel скорее всего где-то внутри Mix определено. В документации Bootstrap считает, что проект простой, поэтому просто выходит с текущей папки в корень и забирает уже по прямому пути файл.

Answer (score 0):

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui bootstrap
npm install
npm run dev
npx mix
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Да вы достали все втирать про этот UI, я в вопросе объяснил что этот пакет устарел, нужен актуальный способ!